# could not find the main class org.testng.remote.remoteTestNg

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

When i run my xml file i get the error, could not find the main class org.testng.remote.remoteTestNg.

Please find the error log

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/remote/RemoteTestNG : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Exception in thread "main"

Answer (score 0):

TestNG need Java7 since 6.9.4.
See https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse is run with java 7 too?